# Insert values in gridview manually using textboxes,loops? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can i insert values in gridview manually.Actually here is my problem.`textboxes` generate dynamically according to `gridview` columns.For examples if gridview columns are 4 then dynamically 4 `textboxes` generated.Now i want when user insert value in 4 `textboxes` and press `submit` button then value insert in `gridview` in first row.User insert again values in `textboxes` then press submit then 2nd row inserted in `gridview`.Keep remember that `gridview` columns is dynamically.No idea about header.We can just insert values in `gridview` by using loop.How can i do this.
Here is my screen shot [image: IMG-LINK]

We can't user header.I'm again telling you.I waana insert values using loops e.g `gridview.[0][0],gridview[0][1]` its just my guess i don't know .Sorry for bad english.
Here is my save button code : code behind

```
public void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = Session["num"].ToString();
    int num = Int32.Parse(s);
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["table"];
    DataRow row1 = t.NewRow();
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        TextBox tt = (TextBox)(form.FindControl("txtser" + i.ToString()));
        string str= tt.Text + " ";
    }
    t.Rows.Add(row1);
    Session["table"] = t;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataSource = t;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Look into the GridView's RowDataBound method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Alternatively you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093576/how-to-extract-rows-from-gridview-in-asp-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to save the entered row data into `HiddenField` and then use it's value for adding a new row to grids data source in code-behind.

**JS**

```
function setRowData() {
    var hdn1 = document.getElementById('hdn1');
    var gv1 = document.getElementById('gv1');
    var cols = gv1.rows[0].cells;

    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
        var col = cols[i].innerHTML; // column name
        var tb = document.getElementById(col); // Column1, Column2, ...
        hdn1.value += col + ':' + tb.value; // key:value pair
        hdn1.value += '~'; // separator
    }

    // remove separator at the end
    hdn1.value = hdn1.value.substring(0, hdn1.value.length - 1);
}
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dt;

    if (Session["dt"] != null) // Submit
    {
        dt = Session["dt"] as DataTable;
    }
    else // !IsPostBack
    {
        dt = GetSampleData();
    }

    gv1.DataSource = dt;
    gv1.DataBind();

    GenerateTextBoxes(dt);

    Session["dt"] = dt;
}

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] keyValue;

    var dt = Session["dt"] as DataTable;
    var dr = dt.NewRow();
    var data = hdn1.Value; // JS set this as "Column1:value1~Column2:value12"
    var pairs = data.Split('~');

    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    { 
        keyValue = pair.Split(':');
        dr[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    hdn1.Value = null;
    Session["dt"] = dt;
    BindGrid();
}

private void GenerateTextBoxes(DataTable dt)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        pn1.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID = col.ColumnName });
    }
}

private DataTable GetSampleData()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));

    var dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Column1"] = "Think 2ce";
    dr["Column2"] = "Code 1ce";

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    return dt;
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv1" />
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pn1">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn1" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" ID="btn1" OnClientClick="setRowData()" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
```